# Cannot interpret memory bandwidth numbers

Tags: performance, x86, memory-bandwidth

I have written a benchmark to compute memory bandwidth:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

double sum_array(double* v, long n)
{
    double s = 0;
    for (long i =0 ; i < n; ++i) {
        s += v[i];
    }
    return s;
}


void BM_MemoryBandwidth(benchmark::State& state) {
    long n = state.range(0);
    double* v = (double*) malloc(state.range(0)*sizeof(double));

    for (auto _ : state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum_array(v, n));
    }
    free(v);
    state.SetComplexityN(state.range(0));
    state.SetBytesProcessed(int64_t(state.range(0))*int64_t(state.iterations())*sizeof(double));
}

BENCHMARK(BM_MemoryBandwidth)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(1<<5, 1<<23)->Complexity(benchmark::oN);


BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

I compile with

```sh
g++-9 -masm=intel -fverbose-asm -S -g -O3 -ffast-math -march=native --std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include memory_bandwidth.cpp
```

This produces a bunch of moves from RAM, and then some `addpd` instructions which `perf` says are hot, so I go into the generated asm and remove them, then assemble and link via

```sh
$ g++-9 -c memory_bandwidth.s -o memory_bandwidth.o
$ g++-9 memory_bandwidth.o -o memory_bandwidth.x -L/usr/local/lib -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main -pthread -fPIC
```

At this point, get a `perf` output that I expect: Movement of data into `xmm` registers, increments of the pointer, and a `jmp` at the end of the loop:

[image: perfmemorybandwidth]

All fine and well up to here. Now here's where things get weird:

I inquire of my hardware what the memory bandwidth is:

```sh
$ sudo lshw -class memory
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
      *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          vendor: AMI
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

So I should be getting at most 8 bytes * 2.4 GHz = 19.2 gigabytes/second.
But instead I get 48 gigabytes/second:

```sh
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                           Time             CPU   Iterations UserCounters...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_MemoryBandwidth/32            6.43 ns         6.43 ns    108045392 bytes_per_second=37.0706G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/64            11.6 ns         11.6 ns     60101462 bytes_per_second=40.9842G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/128           21.4 ns         21.4 ns     32667394 bytes_per_second=44.5464G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/256           47.6 ns         47.6 ns     14712204 bytes_per_second=40.0884G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/512           86.9 ns         86.9 ns      8057225 bytes_per_second=43.9169G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/1024           165 ns          165 ns      4233063 bytes_per_second=46.1437G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/2048           322 ns          322 ns      2173012 bytes_per_second=47.356G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/4096           636 ns          636 ns      1099074 bytes_per_second=47.9781G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/8192          1264 ns         1264 ns       553898 bytes_per_second=48.3047G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/16384         2524 ns         2524 ns       277224 bytes_per_second=48.3688G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/32768         5035 ns         5035 ns       138843 bytes_per_second=48.4882G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/65536        10058 ns        10058 ns        69578 bytes_per_second=48.5455G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/131072       20103 ns        20102 ns        34832 bytes_per_second=48.5802G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/262144       40185 ns        40185 ns        17420 bytes_per_second=48.6035G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/524288       80351 ns        80347 ns         8708 bytes_per_second=48.6171G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/1048576     160855 ns       160851 ns         4353 bytes_per_second=48.5699G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/2097152     321657 ns       321643 ns         2177 bytes_per_second=48.5787G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/4194304     648490 ns       648454 ns         1005 bytes_per_second=48.1915G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth/8388608    1307549 ns      1307485 ns          502 bytes_per_second=47.8017G/s
BM_MemoryBandwidth_BigO          0.16 N          0.16 N
BM_MemoryBandwidth_RMS              1 %             1 %
```

What am I misunderstanding about memory bandwidth that has made my calculations come out wrong by more than a factor of 2?

(Also, this is kinda an insane workflow to empirically determine how much memory bandwidth I have. Is there a better way?)

Full asm for `sum_array` after removing add instructions:

```
_Z9sum_arrayPdl:
.LVL0:
.LFB3624:
    .file 1 "example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp"
    .loc 1 5 1 view -0
    .cfi_startproc
    .loc 1 6 5 view .LVU1
    .loc 1 7 5 view .LVU2
.LBB1545:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:7:     for (long i =0 ; i < n; ++i) {
    .loc 1 7 24 is_stmt 0 view .LVU3
    test    rsi, rsi    # n
    jle .L7 #,
    lea rax, -1[rsi]    # tmp105,
    cmp rax, 1  # tmp105,
    jbe .L8 #,
    mov rdx, rsi    # bnd.299, n
    shr rdx # bnd.299
    sal rdx, 4  # tmp107,
    mov rax, rdi    # ivtmp.311, v
    add rdx, rdi    # _44, v
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0  # vect_s_10.306
.LVL1:
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L5:
    .loc 1 8 9 is_stmt 1 discriminator 2 view .LVU4
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:8:         s += v[i];
    .loc 1 8 11 is_stmt 0 discriminator 2 view .LVU5
    movupd  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rax] # tmp115, MEM[base: _24, offset: 0B]
    add rax, 16 # ivtmp.311,
    .loc 1 8 11 discriminator 2 view .LVU6
    cmp rax, rdx    # ivtmp.311, _44
    jne .L5 #,
    movapd  xmm1, xmm0  # tmp110, vect_s_10.306
    unpckhpd    xmm1, xmm0  # tmp110, vect_s_10.306
    mov rax, rsi    # tmp.301, n
    and rax, -2 # tmp.301,
    test    sil, 1  # n,
    je  .L10    #,
.L3:
.LVL2:
    .loc 1 8 9 is_stmt 1 view .LVU7
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:8:         s += v[i];
    .loc 1 8 11 is_stmt 0 view .LVU8
    addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi+rax*8] # <retval>, *_3
.LVL3:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:7:     for (long i =0 ; i < n; ++i) {
    .loc 1 7 5 view .LVU9
    inc rax # i
.LVL4:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:7:     for (long i =0 ; i < n; ++i) {
    .loc 1 7 24 view .LVU10
    cmp rsi, rax    # n, i
    jle .L1 #,
    .loc 1 8 9 is_stmt 1 view .LVU11
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:8:         s += v[i];
    .loc 1 8 11 is_stmt 0 view .LVU12
    addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi+rax*8] # <retval>, *_6
.LVL5:
    .loc 1 8 11 view .LVU13
    ret
.LVL6:
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L7:
    .loc 1 8 11 view .LVU14
.LBE1545:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:6:     double s = 0;
    .loc 1 6 12 view .LVU15
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0  # <retval>
    .loc 1 10 5 is_stmt 1 view .LVU16
.LVL7:
.L1:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:11: }
    .loc 1 11 1 is_stmt 0 view .LVU17
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L10:
    .loc 1 11 1 view .LVU18
    ret
.LVL8:
.L8:
.LBB1546:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:7:     for (long i =0 ; i < n; ++i) {
    .loc 1 7 15 view .LVU19
    xor eax, eax    # tmp.301
.LBE1546:
# example_code/memory_bandwidth.cpp:6:     double s = 0;
    .loc 1 6 12 view .LVU20
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0  # <retval>
    jmp .L3 #
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3624:
    .size   _Z9sum_arrayPdl, .-_Z9sum_arrayPdl
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
```

Full output of `lshw -class memory`:

```sh
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.90
       date: 10/21/2016
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMU16GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: AMI
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMU16GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: AMI
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

Is the CPU relevant here? Well here's the specs:

```sh
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               94
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G4400 @ 3.30GHz
Stepping:            3
CPU MHz:             3168.660
CPU max MHz:         3300.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            6624.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust erms invpcid rdseed smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp flush_l1d
```

The data produced by the clang compile is much more intelligible. The performance monotonically decreases until it hits 19.8Gb/s as the vector gets much larger than cache:

[image]

Here's the benchmark output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really seem to have much to do with C++ or benchmarking. You're just asking how much memory bandwidth you have and why, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Correct, edited tags accordingly.

Comment: You could also remove some 80% of the question's text...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: True, but then you couldn't reproduce what I'm observing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your benchmarking infrastructure. What is the size of the array? How is bandwidth calculated? It'd be nice to show the code without external dependencies so that others can easily run it on their systems and try to reproduce the same behavior. Also, It'd be useful to show the whole assembly code of the `sum_array` function. What CPU are using? You should confirm whether there is another 8GB DIMM on a *different* memory channel.

Comment: @HadiBrais: The array size grows by a power of two each time from a minimum of 32 doubles to maximum of 8388608 doubles. Unfortunately if I don't use the google benchmark infrastructure I don't get very high quality data. CPU is a low end, low power Intel chip, no avx2 instructions. There are two 8GB RAM chips for a total of 16GB.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Updated with the info you requested.

Comment: What happens, if you remove the `movupd` as well? Does the benchmark change considerably? It is strange that there is no significant time difference between block sizes. The effect of cache should be visible. Maybe your benchmark is not memory-bound at all, so you don't measure memory speed at all.

Comment: I'm suspecting that the array is not initialized before the `sum_array` function is called (which would make most accesses hit in the L1). Try to initialize the array right after allocation e.g., by using `memset` and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know at what frequency your CPU is running during these experiments, but is the bandwidth about 16 bytes per core cycle?

Comment: @HadiBrais: I did the memset thing you recommended, no change at all. Also edited the question with the output of `lscpu` in case there's something there that's relevant.

Comment: @geza: I removed the `movupd` and there was no change in speed! That was even more surprising to me, because it showed that incrementing the pointer and jumping to the loop label is the slow part! (Also looked at this under perf; the je instruction was identified as slow.)

Comment: @geza: I'm not sure how surprised by this I should be, because the original perf output listed 71% of the time in the jne.

Comment: @geza: When I compile with clang, I see performance drop off monotonically with size.

Comment: Have you tested with `memset` for all array sizes (especially the larger ones)? I think we need to measure using perf the events `cache-misses` and `cache-references` for all array sizes. These will enable us to estimate how many accesses actually go to the memory.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Just ran the binary compiled with clang, on the largest input. Got 57% cache miss rate using `perf stat -e cache-misses,cache-references ./memory_bandwidth.x`

Comment: The output from the Clang compiler can be explained by the fact that for small arrays fit in the L1, L2, or L3 cache and the benchmark framework seems to run the same loop multiple times and report the average. Only in the first run the memory bandwidth will play a role, but in all the other runs, the array would be in one of the caches and the bandwidth can easily be higher than the theoretical maximum memory bandwidth (which is about 40GB/s on your system). Notice how when the number of elements exceed 0.5 million (larger than the L3), the bandwidth is smaller than 40GB/s.

Comment: @HadiBrais: The mystery is the gcc build.

Comment: Yes we need to measure cache-misses and cache-references for all array sizes for the gcc build.

Comment: Note that saying "57% cache miss rate" is not very useful because that doesn't enable me to estimate memory bandwidth (by multiplying the number of misses by 64 bytes and dividing that by execution time). I asked for `cache-references` because we may need it depending on `cache-misses`, so you can just measure both with the same amount of effort.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your hardware description that you have two DIMM slots that are placed into two channels.  This interleaves memory between the two DIMM chips, so that memory accesses will be reading from both chips.  (One possibility is that bytes 0-7 are in DIMM1 and bytes 8-15 are in DIMM2, but this depends on the hardware implementation.)  This doubles the memory bandwidth because you're accessing *two* hardware chips instead of one.

Some systems support three or four channels, further increasing the maximum bandwidth.

Comment: How can you tell that I have two DIMM slots that are paired?

Comment: @user14717 `size: 16GiB` for system memory, while your DIMM is `size: 8GiB` (so you have two DIMMs), and also the line with `slot: ChannelA-DIMM1`.

Comment: I see; so my RAM is behaving like a RAID array. Is this standard on modern CPUs?

Comment: Also, and theories on why it's getting 48gb/sec rather than 40gb/second?

Comment: @user14717 That depends a lot on the CPU and memory architecture.  Modern CPUs will typically support this, but the extent (how many channels, how many DIMMs per channel, whether the channel needs to be fully populated) varies.

Comment: Having more than one in DIMM in the same memory channel does not increase the theoretical maximum bandwidth, but it may improve the effective memory bandwdith because the additional parallelism allows more accesses to be in-flight in the same period of time. The reason for this is that the bus of the channel is shared between all the DIMMs. However, if two DIMMs are on two different channels, then the theoretical maximum bandwidth is doubled.

Comment: @HadiBrais I'm never remembering which way the chips go, in one channel or across multiple ones.  I've updated the answer after checking with a motherboard manual I had handy.